# Replace values in array with surrounding null,0

Tags: php, algorithm

So I have a collection of integer values, which is built from a result of another function that can have different values every time. Consider the following in PHP:

```
$arr = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];
```

Which i need to convert to:

```
$newArr = [null,0,2,2,0,null,0,3,3];
```

What i want to accomplish is: If a value is > 0, its neighbours should be 0, and the rest should be null.

What is the best strategy here?

Comment: Answer below :) It should work for you.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your inputs, i have accepted the answer which helped the most by @Casimir et Hippolyte. Keep it up!

Comment: You can always vote up those which worked too ;) Thanks!

Comment: I wish i could but i don't have enough reputation yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with operator precedence:

```
$zero = true;

$arr = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];
$newArr = [];

foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v) {
        $newArr[] = $v;
        $zero = false;
    } else {
        if ($zero and isset($arr[$k+1]) && !$arr[$k+1] || !isset($arr[$k+1]))
            $newArr[] = null;
        else
            $newArr[] = 0;

        $zero = true;
    }
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looping through the entire array, we evaluate each element for three conditions:

1.Element is zero.

2.Previous element is set, and it is equal to zero or null.

3.Next element is set, and it is equal to zero or null.

```
<?php
    foreach($array as $key => $element)
    {
        if($element == 0 && ((isset($array[$key - 1]) && !$array[$key - 1]) || (isset($array[$key + 1]) && !$array[$key + 1])))
        {
            $array[$key] = null;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work for you:

```
<?php
$arr = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];
$new_array = $arr;

$array_count = count($arr);

for ($i=0; $i<$array_count; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0 && $arr[$i+1] == 0) {   
        $new_array[$i] = null;
    } elseif ($i == ($array_count-1) && $arr[$i-1] == 0) {  
        $new_array[$i] = null;
    } elseif ($arr[$i-1] == 0 && $arr[$i+1] == 0) {     
        $new_array[$i] = null;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

We need to check for three conditions: is there, prev. is zero and next is zero.
You can combine first two conditions into the third one.
Broke it down for simplicity.

```
$array = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

    $previous = NULL;
    $next = NULL;

    if (isset($array[$key + 1])) {
        $next = $array[$key + 1];
    }

    if ($key != 0) {
        $previous = $array[$key - 1];
    }

    if ($val === 0 && $next == 0 && $previous == 0) {
        $newArray[] = 'NULL';
    } else {
        $newArray[] = $val;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
$arr = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($arr[$key] > 0 && isset($arr[$key - 1]) && $arr[$key - 1] == 0){
        if(isset($arr[$key - 2]) && $arr[$key - 2] == 0){
            $arr[$key - 2] = null;  
        }
    }
    if($arr[$key] > 0 && isset($arr[$key + 1]) && $arr[$key + 1] == 0){
        if(isset($arr[$key + 2]) && $arr[$key + 2] == 0){
            $arr[$key + 2] = null;  
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here, i am looking for the positive value first then checking and if neighbor is 0 then set neighbor's neighbor to null.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    $arr        = [0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3];
    $extra      = [];


    for($x=0; $x<count($arr); $x++){
        if($arr[$x] == 0){
            $tmp = isset($tmp)?$tmp:[];
            $tmp[]=$x;
        }else{
            if(isset($tmp)){
                $extra[]  = $tmp;
                unset($tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($extra as $subArr){
        if(count($subArr) == 2){
            $arr[$subArr[0]] = null;
            $arr[$subArr[1]] = 0;
        }else if(count($subArr) == 3){
            $arr[$subArr[0]] = 0;
            $arr[$subArr[1]] = null;
            $arr[$subArr[2]] = 0;
        }
    }
    var_dump($arr);
    // YIELDS::
        array (size=9)
          0 => null
          1 => int 0
          2 => int 2
          3 => int 2
          4 => int 0
          5 => null
          6 => int 0
          7 => int 3
          8 => int 3
```